# HP Officejet Pro 8625 sends document to the printer, but doesn't print

Tags: windows-8.1, network-printer, hp-officejet

We have an `HP Officejet Pro 8620`. It connects to the WiFi and we installed the driver on our `Windows 8.1 x64` systems without any issues. However, when we try to print documents, even though it says that they were sent to the printer - they don't actually print.

How can we repair this so that we can print documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the driver, install the [HP Print and Scan Doctor](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&softwareitem=mp-136589-1). It will detect the printer and have an update available. Install the update.

> Windows 8.1 will not print via wireless to this printer without some
>   modification.  Download the latest drivers from the HP website for the
>   8620 series - not from the supplied CD. Then download the "HP Print
>   and Scan Doctor" and run the program. It should render the printer
>   functional with windows 8.1.

Kudos to `irishfred` at [HP OfficeJet Pro 8625 e-All-in-One Printer](http://reviews.costco.com/2070/100116415/united-stationers-hp-officejet-pro-8625-e-all-in-one-printer-reviews/reviews.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Even after installing the HP Print and Scan Doctor and all the updated driver I still had the issue.  My problem was the printer kept going offline.  I found a hotfix that seems to keep the printer from going offline.  Now i've got to change a printer setting to allow the printer to print immediately instead of when it wants to.
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Install-Setup/Officejet-Pro-8625-won-t-print-wirelessly/td-p/4974877

Comment: This does not attempt to explain how to solve the problem in the text or attempt to create a dialog with the question creator to find a solution. Please, when answering a question, do not refer to a link, instead write the solution in the text itself.